# Webapp for iphone switches from home screen to Safari when url parameters are used

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, mobile-safari

I've developed a web app for the iPhone, and I have it bookmarked and added to my iPhone's home screen. I'm noticing a problem with it, though: it works as intended until I navigate to a page within the app that has a query string and parameters - for example, `www.mywebapp.com/page02.html?param1=value&param2=value2` . When I go to a page with such a URL, iOS switches me from the embedded version of Safari to the main Safari app - it takes me out of my app. I don't know why this is happening.

What causes this and what can I do about it?

Comment: What do you mean "switches from the home-screen to Safari"? Does the bookmarked app disappear from the homescreen - or does it switch from a UIWebView-style browser over to Mobile Safari?

Comment: Hi! With "switches..." I mean that the WebApp switches from a UIWebView-style browser over to Mobile Safari as you mentioned. It is strange because it only happens when I use parameters in the URL. I suppose that there will be some restrictions with iphone webapps and url parameters. Do you know any solution for this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)

Answer (score 8):

Many thanks to @BjornKaiser who provided the solution, here is a simple **jQuery** script that will handle this for you for all links.

Add this to the head section of your master ASP.Net page. Make sure you have jquery included:

```
<head>
    <!-- Your reference to your jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          $('a').click(function() {
            document.location = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 5):

That's the way Apple designed it. If you need a multi-view Web App you need to implement the page switching logic in JavaScript. Everything else will cause the problem you described -> jumping to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes this, but [this question about UIWebView issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650988/uiwebview-open-some-links-in-safari-some-within-the-view) has a solution for how to make some links open in the UIWebView page and some open in Mobile Safari, so I bet you could generalize from that to a solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found the best solution: using client-side data storage. You can use JavaScript to store variables information into the variables localStorage and sessionStorage.

Look at these links:
[O'Reilly client-side data storage tutorial](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch05_id35816678.html) and 
[Apple key-value client-side data storage tutorial for web apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW1)